# YUI: Where are forms?

Tags: javascript, html, yui, ria

I am comparing ExtJS and YUI. They seem pretty much tied on the technical side. ExtJs costs money, not much. But YUI is free.

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but ExtJs lets you define [forms](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/dynamic.html). I didn't see forms in YUI. Where are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YUI doesn't have a form component that is similar to the stuff in EXTJS.  You'd have to build it yourself (either from markup, or your own JS).

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS has FormPanels (a container of the widgets that make up a form), a FormLayout (a vehicle to help the developer place labels and input elements in a panel), and a BasicForm (*encapsulates the DOM  element at the heart of the FormPanel class*).  I have seen developers confuse these classes; be warned.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

For forms work with yui I recommend taking a look at http://javascript.neyric.com/inputex/

It offers a simple json based way for defining your forms with validation and all that jazz.